# Diameter and Radius and Well Known Inequality, Which one is preferable?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, graph-theory, computer-science, algebraic-graph-theory

An un-directed graph $G$ is given.

The **diameter** of a graph is the maximum of shortest paths between two vertices of the graph.

$L(S)$ is maximum length of shortest **paths** from $S$ to other vertices.

The radius of a graph is minimum value of $L(S)$ among all vertices.

If $d$ and $r$ be diameter and radius of graph two following inequalities always hold:

$A)$ $r \leq d$

$B)$ $r \geq \frac{d}{2}$

But my note tells me that $B$ is better than of $A$  (maybe by 'better' word, it means that it always holds or any condition that be logical... I don't know for example one of them works with **negative weights** or anything else in Graph)

I see both of them in all of graph books but anyone can distinguish between these two case, is there any difference here that we can prefer $B$ to $A$?

Comment: is it true that tell option $B$ is tighter bound on every $G$?

Comment: for a triangle with edge lengths ${3,-4,5}$, $d=1$ and $r=-1$; here $(A)$ is still valid but $(B)$ is wrong.

Comment: Which you prefer will depend on what you are trying to do. Notice one is an upper bound on $r$ and the other is a lower bound. You can just combine these to $d/2 \leq r \leq d$.

Comment: @MorganRodgers exactly. But really I need a details or discussion (answer of my question here) under which application or which logic the option $B$ is better? sure you are exactly right in combination of these two. I see both of them in books but sure here some experts like you can describe a bit about under which condition $B$ is better. as I told it means one of them is tighter bound? or ....

Comment: I have no idea what "experts" you are referring to (and not demeaning them, just saying I'm missing any context for your statement). But it is meaningless to say which one is a tighter bound; that is only useful for eg comparing two upper bounds or comparing two lower bounds. Bound B is better than bound A if you need a lower bound on $r$ in terms of $d$, but is useless if you need an upper bound on $r$.

Comment: It could be that what is meant is that B is a less obvious fact than A. While A follows immediately from definitions, for B one needs a little bit of thinking. One has to prove that for a certain vertex the radius is at least d/2. For example, can we say that for a path that realizes the diameter there exists a "middle point"?

Answer (score 5):

Let me begin by saying that your question almost makes no sense. As @MorganRodgers very explicitly said, when comparing bounds, you need $2$ lower ones or $2$ higher ones, to find which one is better.

> A an example, here are $2$ upper bounds for $n!$
>
> $$n!<n^n\text{ and } n!<\bigg(\frac{n+1}{2}\bigg)^n$$
>
> The first one comes from the fact that $1,2,...,n-1<n$ and the second
> one comes from the $Am-Gm$ inequality. You can clearly tell that the
> second higher bound is better (or tighter), because it is smaller.

You cannot prefer a lower bound over a higher bound or viceversa. They do different things It's like saying you prefer to draw with a spoon over eating soup with a pencil.

However, I think what you want to prove is the fact that $d-r>r-\frac{d}{2}$, in other words, the lower bound is closer to the actual value than the higher bound.

---

Lets begin by clarifying the notions. Consider a graph $G$ and let the set of the vertices of $G$ be $V(G)$.

> For any pair of vertices $v,u\in V(G)$, the distance between $u$ and
> $v$ is denoted with $d(u,v)$ and is equal to the length of the
> shortest path that connects $u$ and $v$. If $u$ and $v$ are not
> connected this is equal to $\infty$ and if $u=v$ then the distance is
> $0$
>
> For any $v\in V(G)$, the eccentricity of $v$ is denoted by
> $\varepsilon(v)$ and satisfies the following relation
> $$\varepsilon(v)=\max_{u\in V(G),u\neq v}d(u,v)$$
>
> The radius of a graph $G$ is $$r=\min_{v\in V(G)}\varepsilon(v)$$
>
> The diameter of a graph $G$ is $$d=\max_{v\in V(G)}\varepsilon(v)$$

Using what we have just found out, we can see that sometimes the higher bound is closer to $r$ than the lower bound and sometimes the lower bound is closer to $r$ than the higher bound.

For example take a complete graph $K_n$. In this case, $d=r=1$ so $d-r=0<\frac{1}{2}=r-\frac{d}{2}$ so in this case we could say that the higher bound is "better".

But when we take a complete bipartition $K_{n,n}$, $d=2$ and $r=1$ so in this case $d-r=1>0=r-\frac{d}{2}$

---

So to conclude the answer, sometimes the $\frac{d}{2}$ is closer to $r$ and sometimes $d$ is closer to $r$. You cannot prefer a bound over another.